# Ordering Azure Active Directory Graph Results by Created Date

Tags: azure, active-directory

Does anyone know how to order the results of a query to the Azure AD Graph API using the nuget assembly (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient/) by "Created Date" (i.e. when the user was created in the directory?

I can't find any documentation about a property which would contain this.  Is the result set automatically ordered in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a restriction at the moment on the '$orderby' expressions that can be specified for a Graph API query. From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-supported-queries-filters-and-paging-options) -

> The following restrictions apply to $orderby expressions:

- > Two sort orders are currently supported: DisplayName for User and Group    objects, and UserPrincipalName for User objects. The default sort order for users is by UserPrincipalName.

So even if the 'Created Date' was exposed as property on the User I doubt the query will work.